# Cleaning drive and installing Windows

Tags: windows, boot, usb, windows-installation, bootable-media

Today, while trying to install windows on my machine i used rufus on mac instead of the windows media creation tool on windows and that somehow nessed up my installation. Windows booted only after installation and then vanished from boot menu. Upon booting from the installation drive, i received a **missing winload.exe** error. None of the options do anything, the screen just instantly refreshes. 
Now i have a corrupted windows installation and no os to remove it.

How to format the drive?
Will simply creating a bootable usb with the official tool work?

Comment: You should be able to find several options of boot media that you can boot from a usb to reformat the drive. if you can boot off the usb with the windows installation you made you can click repair and go from there to reformat the drive and try again. Alternatively you can just install again and it will format the drive before installing windows.

Comment: Boot from same USB and follow Method 2 here -https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/file-windowssystem32winloadexe-error-code/d64439a9-17ca-49b6-8d63-b41fa78bb608

Comment: Thank you @user52599 this worked!